# Show all tray icons in Windows permanently

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, notification-area

Is there a way to show all tray icons in the Windows Task Bar of Windows XP, permanently?

I don't like to go over tray icons and extend them each time I need to see a specific icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click on your `Start` button
2. Select `Properties`
3. Select `Taskbar` tab
4. Uncheck `Hide inactive icons`
5. Click `OK`

[image]